# when the time of system is wrong ,how can I get correct time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

```
let currentDate = new Date();
```

CurrentDate is related to the time of system, so if the time of system is wrong ,currentDate will be wrong.

Comment: Connect to server that has correct timestamp and use that timestamp as *current date* instead

Answer (score 3):

You could use an atomic clock API, such as World Clock:

http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now

```
{
    "$id":"1", "currentDateTime":"2018-10-26T05:27-04:00", "utcOffset":"-04:00:00",
    "isDayLightSavingsTime":true, "dayOfTheWeek":"Friday",
    "timeZoneName":"Eastern Standard Time", "currentFileTime":131850052212461578,
    "ordinalDate":"2018-299", "serviceResponse":null
}
```

The only downside to this is that it would require making a REST call.  So there would be latency between the JavaScript call and when you get your response.  You could also expose your own endpoint on the server side, if you have control over that.

Comment: if i use clock API,i do not know the api is safe.Is there other method?I do not want reply other api;

Comment: Then build your own trusted API, which only your authenticated users/apps can access.  If you can't use your system time, and you also can't use someone else's system time, then you're pretty much out of options, right?

Answer (score 1):

If HTTP request is an option:

```
let dateNow;
fetch('http://currentmillis.com/time/minutes-since-unix-epoch.php')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(min => {
    dateNow = new Date(parseInt(min) * 1000 * 60);
    console.log(dateNow);
  });
```

### Explanation

The API returns minutes passed since epoch, for performance reasons. Convert it to milliseconds and then construct your date object

Comment: If I want show correct date always on page,i need get http request every second??

Comment: @柠檬不酸—no, you should be able to determine a difference between the local and time server clocks and just apply the difference to local calls. Check with the time server at maybe 1 or even 10 minute intervals if you think the local system clock might be changing unpredictably.

Comment: @RobG the API doesn't give current milli. They change only every 1 minute so that they can do caching